# PHP PDO bit value returns string

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, bit

I have a lot of tables which has bit fields. For ex:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` VARCHAR(150) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `surname` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `gsm` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `citizen_id` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `is_driver` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `is_activated` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `is_deleted` BIT(1) NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

At localhost is_activated comes as `string(1) "1"` but at my hosting `string(1) ""`. I already found it's need to read with [ord](http://php.net/ord). But i do not want to change all files for this. I throught there is a way to doing this but couldnt found yet.

---

### My local:

**PDO Driver for MySQL:**

mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id:241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $

**MySQL:**

5.7.12

### Hosting

**Client API version:**

5.5.50

**MySQL:**

5.5.0

Comment: Why are you using `BIT(1)` fields instead of `BOOLEAN`?

Comment: Is boolean = tinyint(1) ? If yes is this effective than bit ? I mean which will store less byte in storage

Comment: They both use one byte.

Comment: Thanks for replies @Scopey